How much should my aliens weigh?
My aliens are trans-humanoid Mammalian creatures here is the info you will need to help me calculate the weight.
The males stand at 14ft-19ft tall where as the females are 16ft-24ft. both sexes are purple in hue ALWAYS. They all have four Ant-like mandibles. They all have two large eyes, and two false eyes to trick predators. They all have ears in their head versus outside (similar) to a caterpillar. They all have a rather large gut, and have three stomach chambers (so they can digest heavy plants similar to how cows eat). And they have three pairs of teats (six in total), and instead of a nose the have two thick umbilical-cord-like growths that are permanently hanging from then sides of their neck all the way down to the first pair of teats (which is placed in the same spot as human teats). They all have four large bulky strong arms that end in three strong fingers that end with 6in claws. They all have bulky STRONG legs that are built similarly to a kangaroos legs (but without the fur, in fact my aliens don’t have fur because their land is constantly the perfect temperature). The feet have three toes with long 6in claws. They all have a long thick tail about 6ft long on average. And the males and ONLY the males have small horns that line from the top of their head down the tip of their tail (They have these to attract a mate).
I hope that infos enough if it’s not I will include pics of my creatures that I sketched when I was about 11 almost 12

This is a straightforward application of the square-cube law. Most of the details don't really matter other than the basic dimensions of the creature.
A humanoid 3-4x the height of a human, with the same basic body plan, weighs 27-64x as much. Starting with a heavy-set 300lb human to mimic the body type, these creatures could weigh anywhere from about 5,000lb to perhaps 20,000lb. Maybe add a bit more for the tail and extra arms. This is of course extremely heavy and may strain or breaks the limits of known biology, but that never got in the way of a good story.

Dang that’s a bit heavy. My aliens are supposed to live for about 200 years but I don’t think they can take the strain for that long…

@Algarivian_Official-MAIN.WBSE Indeed, there's a good reason why there's few examples of very large land animals, and none as large as the ones you're describing. Maybe they live on a planet with less gravity.

Umm no.. it’s 1.4 times as strong as earths…

@Algarivian_Official-MAIN.WBSE As a general rule, the bigger the planet, the smaller the life forms can be.  At your higher gravity, I don't think that body plan will work for anything much bigger than a bear.   That said, if you are willing to go with Earth like gravity, this weight is pretty consistent with a t-rex; so, it might actually work at 1g if you assume dinosaur like bones.

Well yes their bones are MASSIVE I can edit the question to include a picture of a sketch I made of the anatomy if you would like.

@Algarivian_Official-MAIN.WBSE - if their bones are particularly massive, that will also make them more massive.  Past a certain point, you experience diminishing returns.

Don't forget that their world may have lighter gravity, and their bones may be stronger than terrestrial mammalian bones.  It doesn't necessarily follow that they're getting too heavy to have a long life.

By all means, please edit in a picture of their skeleton.  It'll help gauge their mass better, especially if you can say what it's made from, and how hollow the skeleton may be.

@Algarivian_Official-MAIN.WBSE I don’t think they can take the strain for that long Per the [help/on-topic], we help people build imaginary worlds. Don't let today's fetish for "all things as realistic as possible" get in the way of a good story built on a good world. Stop worrying about how your creatures will live 200 years. Unless "how" is a critical plot point in your story, ignore it (exercise narrative parsimony) and move forward.

I concur with JBH. Ageing is a complex process that is engraved in our DNA, and there are current scientists studying it and dreaming of 'deactivating' it so humans could become, in theory, immortal. If your creatures can live at all, there's absolutely no reason why they can't live up to 200 years old or more. Don't worry about being realistic, worry about internal consistence: a creature that big, and evolved in a planet with constant temperatures is not going to survive the temperature changes of a single day on Earth; they will die of a heat stroke without external cooling.

Thanks for the feedback.

I added the anatomy! Time to analyze!

Can anyone help calculate the tail weight?
